How to indicate absolute pivot highs and lows?
I am new to pine script. I would like to have absolute pivot highs and lows shown on Tradingview.
I found the code by LonesomeTheBlue below that is close to what I am looking for.
//@version=4
study("Pivot High Low Points", overlay =true)
lb = input(defval = 1, title="Left Bars")
rb = input(defval = 1, title="Right Bars")

mb = lb + rb + 1

plotshape(iff(not na(high[mb]), iff(highestbars(mb) == -lb, high[lb], na), na), style = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar, color = color.lime, size = size.tiny, offset = -lb)
plotshape(iff(not na(low[mb]), iff(lowestbars(mb) == -lb, low[lb], na), na), style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.red, size = size.tiny, offset = -lb)

However, the candle is labeled even when it is at equal high/low with the adjacent (right) candle. The triangle shape would not go away in this case.
I wanted to show only the candle with an absolute pivot high/low. I wonder how to do this? I greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.

I am providing here the version 5 of the same exact code you have provided in your question, hope it helps you.
//@version=5
indicator("Pivot High Low Points", overlay =true)

lb = input.int(defval = 5, title="Left Bars")
rb = input.int(defval = 5, title="Right Bars")

mb = lb + rb + 1

plotshape((not na(high[mb]) ? ((ta.highestbars(mb) == -lb) ? high[lb] : na) : na), style = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar, color = color.lime, size = size.tiny, offset = -lb)

plotshape((not na(low[mb]) ? ((ta.lowestbars(mb) == -lb ) ? low[lb] : na) : na), style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.red, size = size.tiny, offset = -lb)


Basically what it does is gets the Pivot high and low based on the lb and rb values and plots a up triangle for low with red and down triangle in green for highs.


Your approach is exactly what I was looking for. Taking into account both lb and rb values. However, the chart looks the same as before with the version 5 code provided. Candles are labeled even when they are at equal high/low with the right ones.

Pls change the default value from 1 to 5 or 9 , you would see a difference.
